# Создать свойство по строке

Tags: рекурсия, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Прошу прощения, вопрос идиотский и детский, но очень важный для меня на текущем этапе.
Итак:

Есть следующее,

```
var ksu = {};
var tmp = "ksu.Core.object.Test";
```

Задача:

Создать в объекте эти же свойства, опираясь на текст: "ksu.Core.object.Test".
Понимаю, нужно прибегнуть к рекурсии, но что-то не получается. Простите, реально, я деградирую в отпуске жесточайше.

Спасибо за помощь.

Как я пытался сие реализовать:

Я пытался создавать свойство объекта и вызывать саму себя (функцию) с аргументом, который и есть новое свойство объекта. Таким образом и хотел выстроить цепочку. А сама строка сплитилась по точке и при очередном вызове из массива удалялся используемый элемент. Не прокатило.

Comment: да я чето плохо соображаю при +40 =), но мне кажется надо просто идти по элементам массива tmp и добавлять их в ksu, а он уже и будет объектом со свойствами...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, еще раз убеждаюсь, что хочешь что-то сделать хорошо, сиди в баре и пей пиво :D

Если кому интересно - то вот и функция :D

```
function createObj (str) {
    var obj = {};
    var list = str.split('.');
    var fun = function(list, index) {
        if (index > list.length - 1)
            return {};
        var key = list[index];
        var object = {};
        object[key] = fun(list, index + 1);
        return  object;
    }
    return fun(list, 0);
};
```

Comment: ну наверно правильно, просто чем тут усложнять рекурсией? у тебя же в list - уже список параметров, просо идешь по нему и добавляешь свойства..

Answer (score 4):

Без рекурсии:

```
var ksu = {};
var tmp = "ksu.Core.object.Test";
var keys = tmp.split('.');
for(var i = keys.length; i--;){
    var tmpObj = {}; 
    tmpObj[keys[i]] = ksu;   
    ksu = tmpObj;    
}
console.log(ksu);
```